# Java BeanGenerator property name problem with open parenthesis '('

Tags: java, cglib

I create a `BeanGenerator` object and `addProperties` Like this.

```java
final BeanGenerator beanGenerator = new BeanGenerator();
final Map<String, Class<?>> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("name", String.class);
properties.put("`name", String.class);
properties.put("~name", String.class);
properties.put("!name", String.class);
properties.put("@name", String.class);
properties.put(")name", String.class);
properties.put("(name", String.class); // Problem !!!
BeanGenerator.addProperties(beanGenerator, properties);
```

It runs without any errors even if i use informal characters like `` `~!@#$%^&*)-+= `` for property name.

but when i use open parenthes `(` for property name

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name 'get(name' is invalid
```

is occurred.

Why ? and how property name can contains `(` ?

Comment: A quick search tells me there's a bunch of classes called `BeanGenerator` in various libs. Which one is this from?

Comment: looks like [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib/blob/master/cglib/src/main/java/net/sf/cglib/beans/BeanGenerator.java)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca org.springframework.cglib.beans.BeanGenerator

Comment: *dang* this is old!!(spring-version??) spring [current package description](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/cglib/core/package-summary.html) says: "Spring's repackaging of the CGLIB core package **(for internal use only)**"

Answer (score 1):

### Why ?

The error message comes from: [Signature constructor](https://github.com/cglib/cglib/blob/975e481faf39c91b8ac5b9b3d62822b7c52c5f47/cglib/src/main/java/net/sf/cglib/core/Signature.java#L29).

It is poorly documented, obviously "in work" (TO-DO), but also the only "validation rule" which applies.:
**"Property key may not contain `(` character."**

---

### how property name can contains ( ?

Not with cglib /-out forking it(/contributing to the project;)!

But even if, we will run into (next) trouble.... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8

Comment: from my opinion they the keys should confirm with [Java#Identifiers-Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) (cglib prepends only `get` resp. `set` ..to these)

Comment: the key names are dynamic auto generated Columns from Sql  Stored Procedure . so i have to create dynamic POJO by BeanGenerator . I wish i could change the names but i am not allowed .

Comment: If you can't change the format: Transform it! (with a script/regex/job/.../"sledge hammer")